# NSPredicate for Not Equal To not working

Tags: objective-c, nspredicate

I am trying to get the following `NSPredicate` to work without success:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"obsSchoolName == '%@' AND obsStatus != 'paused'", currentSchool]];
```

There are 4 records, and one is set with obsStatus as 'paused'

It shows all 4 records if I remove obsStatus != 'paused'.

If I put obsStatus == 'paused' it shows the one record with obsStatus as 'paused'.

But with obsStatus != 'paused' I get no records at all.

Any ideas?

I have also tried:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"obsSchoolName == '%@' AND obsStatus != 'paused'", currentSchool];

NOT(obsStatus == 'paused')
obsStatus <> 'paused'
```

Comment: Get rid of the improper use of `stringWithFormat:`. That may be getting in the way.

Comment: `predicateWithFormat` is already designed to take a format string and a list of arguments. Look at the documentation for it and look at the examples shown at https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the single quotes around the school name substitution. (@Tony did that correctly, but assumes incorrectly that the substitution is with a dynamic property).

```
NSDictionary *r0 = @{ @"obsSchoolName": @"UCLA", @"obsStatus":@"not paused" };
NSDictionary *r1 = @{ @"obsSchoolName": @"UCLA", @"obsStatus":@"not paused" };
NSDictionary *r2 = @{ @"obsSchoolName": @"UCLA", @"obsStatus":@"paused" };
NSDictionary *r3 = @{ @"obsSchoolName": @"UCLA", @"obsStatus":@"not paused" };
NSDictionary *r4 = @{ @"obsSchoolName": @"USC", @"obsStatus":@"not paused" };
NSArray *records = @[r0, r1, r2, r3, r4];

NSString *currentSchool = @"UCLA";
// note: NOT obsSchoolName == '%@'
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"obsSchoolName == %@ AND obsStatus != 'paused'", currentSchool];
NSArray *filtered = [records filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
NSLog(@"%@", filtered);
```

Comment: Great. It makes me wonder the app had been working for the last few years!! Re-written all predicates and all good. Thanks.